# navigator.share(shareData) is not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, progressive-web-apps

I just want to activate native apps, when clicking on the "share" `button` on my `PWA (Progressive Web App)` but it shows the following error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined

I am using `Nuxt Js`

This is My code

```
function tshareData(i) {
  if (/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|OperaMini/i.test(
     navigator.userAgent)
  ) {
    try {
      let y = document.getElementById("sharetable" + i).innerText;
      const shareData = {
        title: "List",
        text: y,
        url: window.location.href
      };
      navigator
        .share(...shareData)
        .then(() => console.log("Successful share"))
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Catch Error", error);
    }
  } else {
    alert("Browser Not Suported");
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

In general, you should use [feature detection](https://web.dev/web-share/#sharing-links-and-text) via

```
if (navigator.share) {
  // Web Share is available.
}
```

before attempting to use the Web Share API. Detection based on `navigator.userAgent` string matching is not a good idea.

As for the actual error you're reporting, it doesn't necessarily sound like it's coming from the usage of the Web Share API, as none of the code in your snippet actually calls an `apply()` method on anything. You should take a look at the stack trace associated with the exception and figure out what underlying code is actually calling `apply()`.